# Django QuerySet Issue

Tags: django, orm

I have a model with a column `team_id` that can be null. I want to check if it is `null` or `None`.

```
    team_id = Profile.objects.values_list('team_id').filter(user_id=request.user)
    print(team_id)

    if not team_id:
        print("none")
    else:
        print("not none")
```

I get the following output:

```
<QuerySet [(None,)]>
not none
```

So `team_id` is `None` but it still prints out `not none`. I googled and searched many times but the solution is same as mine. I also tried this:

```
if team_id is not None:
```

But gave me the same result...Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Because you've got a list containing a tuple containing the single value None. The list itself does not equal None.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is only one record per user, which appears to be the case from your description/code:

```
try:
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
    if profile.team_id:
        print 'not none'
    else:
        print 'none'
except Profile.DoesNotExist:
    print 'profile not found'
```